# Wrap N-arg function into another function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, std-function

I have a function which executes another function in worker thread:

```
void run_in_worker_thread( std::function< void( ) > proc )
```

Now I would like to implement function **schedule()** which takes **proc()** function as argument and returns function which executes **proc()** in worker thread via **run_in_worker_thread()**.

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
  public:
    void run_in_worker_thread( std::function< void( ) > proc )
    {
            std::cout << "execute in worker thread\n";
            proc();
    }

    template < class... TArgs >
    std::function< void( TArgs... ) >
    schedule( std::function< void( TArgs... ) > proc )
    {
        std::function< void( TArgs... ) > f
                = [this, proc]( TArgs... args ) { run_in_worker_thread( [=]( ) { proc( args... ); } ); };
        return f;
    }  
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    std::function<void(int, int)> my_funciton = 
         [](int a, int b) {std::cout << "got " << a << " and " << b << "\n";};
    auto f2 = test.schedule( my_funciton );
    f2(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my **schedule()** requires std::function as argument. For instance, the following call leads to a compilation error:

```
    auto my_funciton = [](int a, int b) {std::cout << "got " << a << " and " << b << "\n";};
    auto f2 = test.schedule( my_funciton );
```

Comment: "*The problem is that my schedule() requires std::function as argument*" So... don't take it as an argument.

Comment: No, the problem is not that your `schedule()` requires a `std::function` argument. The problem is that you're attempting to pass in a lambda that takes two parameters to be called. Where do you expect those two parameters to come from? C++ can't make them appear out of thin air. The `std::function` that gets called in the child thread receives no parameters whatsoever.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the question is how to describe this argument...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, you didn't get the question. schedule() generates function. When user calls this function he passes arguments and I need to deliver that arguments to worker thread somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a `std::function` is a polymorphic wrapper around a callable object. Lambdas are not `std::function`s. Just like string literals are not `std::string`s. In your first example, you do this:

```
std::function<void(int, int)> my_funciton = 
     [](int a, int b) {std::cout << "got " << a << " and " << b << "\n";};
```

You're constructing a `std::function` from the lambda. The `schedule` function is able to deduce the signature of the function without problems.

In your second example, you do this:

```
auto my_funciton = [](int a, int b) {std::cout << "got " << a << " and " << b << "\n";};
```

Then you get an error because `std::function<void (Args...)>` can't be matched against the lambda. The solution to this is to allow `schedule` to accept any callable object, not just `std::function`.

```
template <typename Func>
auto schedule(Func proc) {
  return [this, proc](auto... args) {
    run_in_worker_thread([=]() {
      proc(args...);
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The proposed solution does exactly what I need but unfortunately, I have only C++14 which doesn't support  **auto...**. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think you're mistaken. Generic lambdas were added in C++14.

Comment: @VadymHulakov Are you using a compiler that only has partial support for C++14?

Comment: I use g++ 5.4.0

Comment: The error is `cannot call member function ‘void Test::run_in_worker_thread(std::function<void()>)’ without object`

Comment: I replaced `run_in_worker_thread` with `this->run_in_worker_thread` and now it works! Thank you!